# why when I type echo <?php ?> in inspect element auto command becomes <---?php ?--->?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make a php tag but through echo, and why does the input I get instead become an automatic command?

which was originally :

```
<?php

public function section(string $name)
  {
    $this->nameSection = $name;
    echo '<?php echo ' . $this->nameSection;
  }

  public function endSection()
  {
    echo "?>";
  }
```

Becomes :

```
<!--?php ---?>
```

oh yes I call them like this :

```
<?php $kurumi->section("content") ?>

<?php $kurumi->endSection() ?>
```

my intention want to fill variable with html tag

and I want to get <?php ?> output in inspect element

Comment: The browser tries to interpret <? as an HTML tag and when it fails it probably just comments it out. If you want to display the literal `<?php` on your page use `htmlentities("<?php echo '...' ?>")` to escape the tag opening and closing characters. If you want to actually interpret the PHP code, then that's a different situation

Comment: @apokryfos `<?` denotes SGML/XML directives, not HTML elements.

Comment: @Dai `<?php` is the PHP opening tag and `<?` is also the PHP short opening tag in addition to possibly being XML directives. Both of these are irrelevant to a browser trying to interpret what is most likely an HTML 5 document which is probably why they get commented out.

Comment: @apokryfos The OP is doing `cho '<?php echo ' ` so the browser _will_ see `<?php`.

Comment: @Dai  The browser will see `<?php` will not recognize it as a valid HTML tag and will comment it out. Why does it matter if `<?` is for XML directives or for PHP short tags? The browser doesn't deal with either in HTML documents

Comment: thank you all, I understand about all of your explanations